# displayName of file not available when getting contents of folder in BIM 360 Docs

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I am trying to list the names of the files in a folder in BIM 360, but I'm having trouble retrieving the names of the files.

When using the `GET projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents` endpoint of the Data Management API, I notice different results when listing files in an A360 project versus a BIM 360 project.

On A360, the value of key `data[].attributes.displayName` is the name of the file, such as `Test.nwd`. However, on BIM 360, the `displayName` seems to always be an empty string.

I did notice that if I use the `GET projects/:project_id/items/:item_id` endpoint to retrieve the details of an individual item, the `data.attributes.displayName` is still blank but the name of the file *does* appear in the `included[].attributes.displayName` key under the entry with `"type": "versions"`.

**Does anyone have an idea as to why the `displayName` of items are blank when listing folder contents in BIM 360?**

In theory I could achieve my desired result by retrieving the folder contents and then retrieving the details of each item, but I would prefer not to have to make an additional API call for each item in a folder.

Comment: I gave it a test with my BIM project to check the contents of Plan or my custom folder. The display name is shown up correctly. I doubt if your file name in BIM 360 happens to contain some special characters, or specific language? 
if you still have the problem, please add a header 'X-Request-ID' with an unique string when posting GET projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents. Then you can email us at forge.help@autodesk.com with the X-Request-ID value. I will try to look for the related information at server side.

Comment: @XiaodongLiang thanks for the response. I tried simplifying the name of one of my files by changing it to just English letters, but that didn't seem to have any effect. I did as you suggested and sent a request with the `X-Request-ID` header and passed that along in an email to forge.help. I did notice that `displayName` is available in the `versions` entries under the `included` key (instead of `data`), so I might just have to use those instead.

Comment: my apology. I happened to check 3D model only yesterday. While when I checked again today, I did saw the behavior 'display name = empty'. It looks it occurs on 2D sheet only. I am checking with engineer team, and also asking them to take a look at the record of your specific request with X-Request-ID.

Comment: as writing of today, the issue has been solved. Please check if it is also working at your side.

Comment: @XiaodongLiang yes it does seem to be working now. Thank you!